# Efficient implementation of rolling MAD/Hampel filter

Tags: filters, non-linear, software-implementation, reference-implementation

I have implemented the moving median absolute deviation (moving MAD) and it seems like bit-exact to [Matlab's implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/filter.html?highlight=hampel#impulse-detection-example). Nevertheless, I am sure that it is not efficient.

The usual median filter should be implemented with a double heap. The moving MAD can not be implemented this way since the absolute deviation of each element in the window can be extremely modified with any modification of the median. This forces using the quick-select for every sample, which makes the calculation very long...

Somehow, Matlab managed to implement moving MAD with computation time only twice the median filter. This suggests that they somehow managed to use a double median filter. Any ideas on how to implement it?

**Edit:**
**After a couple of years I think I have found the answer and implemented it in the attached code**. Please find it below

Comment: While I **have** written a sliding $\min()$ or sliding $max()$ algorithm that has complexity proportional to $\log_2(B)$ where $B$ is the buffer length, and I understand how to split that into two simultaneous sliding min **and** max for the top and bottom halves of the data (and the sliding median would be the average of the max of the bottom half buffer and the min of the top half buffer), i have never written the program that is an efficient sliding median.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson most popular implementation of the sliding-median is the median-heap. I think that there are many implementations that you can find on the web...

Comment: You could also review the source code for the median filter implemented in python scipy.ndimage.median_filter

Comment: @Dan Boschen , I was looking for an efficient implementation of the median filter - which I have. I was looking for an efficient implementation of the rolling MAD, which is closely related to the Hampel filter. Unlike the  median filter, the Hampel filter modifies the signal in only at the locations which are marked as spike

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by the **orignial** answer by @Bob, which he found not correct but had many of the elements that I will use here.

For simplicity, let us assume that we have the rolling median from an already implemented median filter with length $w$. From all the elements within the window, there are $z = \frac{w-1}{2}$ values that maintain $|v - m| >= MAD$, where $m$ is the already found median of the window. Here we emphasize that **we use $v$ only for the elements that maintain this condition** and ignore the rest of the elements.

Let us mark $h \in \{v|v\ge m\}, l \in \{v|v\le m\}$. Following we can define two new elements from the window, $o_1, o_2$ for which we define the following two group of conditions:

1. conditions on values
   $$h - m\ge o_1 - m$$
   $$m - l\ge o_1 - m$$
   $$h - m\ge m - o_2$$
   $$m - l\ge m - o_2$$
2. condition on orders
   $$\text{ord}(o_1) - \text{ord}(o_2) = z$$

Therefore, all we have to do is to create two median heaps with the second condition and use the following actions iteratively for each new value entering the window:

1. Maintain the median heaps.
2. Increase/decrease the orders of both of the heaps to maintain condition 1.
3. The MAD is the maximal deviation produced by one of the two limit order values.

Since the maintenance of the median heaps is of logarithmic order of complexity, this solution logarithmic order of complexity. The code for this solution is [attached here](https://github.com/ggkogan/hampel).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly. If you add a pseudo-code it could help.

If I understood correctly. after taking into account the complexity of balancing the heaps, this algorithm has worst case `O(W * log(W))`.

As you wrote ~absolute deviation of each element in the window can be extremely modified with any modification of the median~

Comment: Suppose window size 1001 and input as alternating +1, -1. The median will be alternating +1 and -1.

If the heaps are exclude the values equal to the median. Every iteration ~500 elements become smaller/larger than the median.

Or you would keep only two counters of ~500

Comment: Also, how do you compute the `median(abs(X - median(X)))` given the state?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, maybe your algorithm works as you said, only the description is incomplete. By the way I liked this problem. What are the applications for of this filter?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hampel.html

Comment: @Bob, you are right, I still have to show an implementation...

Comment: After reading your matworks hampel link. I would highlight two things. (1) if you are using a window as small as 6 you shouldn't care too much about using a heap at all. (2) the algorithm described there is not calculating the median absolute deviation, it is estimating `median(abs(X - median(X))` from `mean(abs(X - median(X))`.

Comment: the default window is 7 but it can be different. Also, "It also **estimates the standard deviation** of each sample about its window median **using the median absolute deviation**." Which is vise versa of what you have written, no?

Comment: @Bob, I attached the implementation. Feel free to tell me what you think of it

Answer (score 1):

The median-heap algorithm as you probably know keeps two heaps.

One possible efficient solution would be to implement a heap based on a [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), that on any operation keeps track of `sum` and `size` of each subtree.

Then you can implement an algorithm that will find the `median(abs(X - median(X)))`, as well as the node that splits the nodes in `median(X) - median(X - median(X))` and `median(X) + median(X - median(X))`

Let

- `nm` be the first node with value greater than `median(X)`
- `nl` the first node with value not less than `median(X) - median(abs(X - median(X)))`
- `nr` the last node with value not greater than `median(X) + median(abs(X + median(X)))`

For simplicity let's consider only the odd sized case.

To find `nl` and `nr` we use the fact that half of the nodes are between `nl` and `nr` and that there is no node `n` with `abs(median(X) - n.value)` between `median(X) - nl.value` and `nr.value - median(X)`.

```py
def find_mid_section(root, medianX, N):
  while ri - li != N / 2
    if ri - li < N / 2:
      nl, nr, li, ri = expand_mid_section(nl, nr, li, ri, medianX, N)
    else ri - li > N / 2:
      nl, nr, li, ri = contract_mid_section(nl, nr, li, ri, medianX, N)


def expand_mid_section(nl, nr, li, ri, medianX, N):
  '''
    Move left to the left node or right node to the right
    whichever gives the least expansion
  '''
  if nl.left and nr.right:
    if medianX - nl.left.value < nr.right.value - medianX:
      nl, li = move_left(nl, li)
    else:
      nr, ri = move_right(nr, ri)
  if nl.left:
    nl, li = move_left(nl, li)
  else:
    nr, ri = move_right(nr, ri)
  return nl, nr, li, ri


def contract_mid_section(nl, nr, li, ri, medianX, N):
  '''
    Move left node to the right node or right to the left
    whichever gives the least contraction
  '''
  if nl.right and nr.left:
    if medianX - nl.right.value > nr.left.value - medianX:
      nl, li = move_right(nl, li)
    else:
      nr, ri = move_left(nr, ri)
  if nl.left:
    nl, li = move_left(nl, li)
  else:
    nr, ri = move_right(nr, ri)
  return nl, nr, li, ri



def move_left(n, i):
  n = n.left
  i -= 1
  if n.right:
    i -= n.right.size
  return n, i

def move_right(n, i):
  n = n.right
  i += 1
  if n.left:
    i += n.left.size
  return n, i
```

The median can be obtained by an index search.

The sum can be computed by a value search adding the values of each node, for instance, sum all the values strictly to the left of a value

```py
def get_sum_lt(root, v):
  n = root
  sum = root.left.sum
  while n:
    if n.value < v:
      sum += n.value
      n = n.right
      sum += n.left.sum
    else:
      n = n.left
      sum = n.right.sum + n.value
```

After adding one would call `add_to_branch(n, n.value, 1)`, before removing a value one would call `add_to_branch(n, -n.value, -1)` to update the ancestors of a node.

```py
def add_to_branch(n, sum, size):
  while n.parent:
    n = n.parent
    n.sum += sum
    n.size += size
```

I am not giving the complete algorithm, but only the key ideas that you can use to compute the moving MAD with complexity `O((N-W)*log(W))`, where `N` is the input size and `W` is the window size.

Comment: I am not quite sure that I am following you. As the first line is missing the Median expression, are you deriving the MAD or AAD? Also, count(h) and count(l) are equal by definition, no?

Comment: I am deriving median absolute deviation, $MAD(X)$ above would be written as `sum(abs(X - median(X))` in Matlab. I can imagine an implementation where for an odd size sample the median is in one of the heaps, in that case $count(h) - count(l) = \pm 1$

Comment: So, for MAD should not it be MAD(X)=median(|X-m|)? Maybe it would be more clear if you will start from the definition and show the missing step. Sorry for the inconvenience, I am probably missing something...

Comment: Sorry, I misread the definition of `MAD(X)`, sorry. I posted an update to the answer. Unfortunately I couldn't think of a way to explain the algorithm without going to the underlying data structure, so I wrote a sort of pseudo code.

Comment: I have to admit that I am yet not following all the answer. How the sums are related to the MAD?

Comment: Hi, I have found a solution I understand. It seems surprisingly simple. Please tell me what you think of it.